# How to give image source in wordpress page editor?

Tags: images, pages, homepage, filesystem

I have image file stored inside theme directory called site.

Now in my home page using wordpress page editor I have put the following code but it didn't display image, seems location is wrong.

```
<img src="site/images/footLogo.png" style="padding: 0px!important; color:white">
```

let me know what issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define constant in theme function file as:

```
if( !defined(THEME_IMG_PATH)){
   define( 'THEME_IMG_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/site/images' );
  }
```

and then you can use img tag as

```
 <img src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>/footLogo.png" style="padding: 0px!important; color:white">
```

Answer (score 2):

### Absolute URLs

As other have said, you need to use the full URL for your image `src` attribute, or the browser will not be able to find it.

WordPress provides the function `get_template_directory_uri()` that returns the full URL to your theme path.

So, by doing:

```
<?php
$img_src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/site/images/footLogo.png';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $img_src ?>" style="padding: 0px!important; color:white">
```

your image will be shown, assuming the path is correct and the file is there.

### Helper function

If you have more images, and you want to ease the process of output them in templates you can create a custom function that wraps `get_template_directory_uri()`.

For example:

```
function theme_image( $image ) {
  return get_template_directory_uri() . '/site/images/' . $image;
}
```

and then in templates do:

```
<img src="<?php echo theme_image('footLogo.png') ?>" 
     style="padding: 0px!important; color:white">
```

### WordPress 4.7+ and "parent theme fallback"

If you use WP 4.7+ code, you will have access to the new function `get_theme_file_uri()`.

The benefit of this function over  `get_template_directory_uri()` is that it automatically loads the file from child theme if available.

So, for example, if you change the `theme_image()` function to:

```
function theme_image( $image ) {
  return get_theme_file_uri( '/site/images/' . $image );
}
```

when you do `theme_image('footLogo.png')` the image `'footLogo.png'` will be loaded from child theme, if child theme is in use and the file is available there, otherwise will be loaded from parent theme.

This new feature provides a "parent theme fallback" that pairs with the "template parent theme fallback" from parent to child themes that has been there since WP 3.0 through functions like `get_template_part()`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use PHP in the content editor, just write the full path to your image.

```
<img src="/css/_include/img/slider-images/1.jpg" alt="Image" data-fullwidthcentering="on">
```

Comment: Wordpress comments out php written in the edtior.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to copy the full path to the image like so:
`http://www.your-site-name.extension/wp-content/themes/site/images/footLogo.png` in your `<img src="">`.

WordPress works with absolute urls.